# how do I configure django-notifications in views

Tags: django, django-views

I have an app where employees can post a work request order for the support team. I'm trying to configure it where once the request form is saved, a notification is sent to a representative of the support team. Using django-notifications, I've created the management.py file...

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_noop as _

if "notification" in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    from notification import models as notification

def create_notice_types(app, created_models, verbosity, **kwargs):
    notification.create_notice_type("post_request", _("Post Request Received"), _("you have received a Post Request"))

    signals.post_syncdb.connect(create_notice_types, sender=notification)
else:
    print "Skipping creation of NoticeTypes as notification app not found"
```

but, I'm having difficulty with the proper syntax in the view function. As written its:

```
def create_record(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostRequestForm(request.POST)
        user = User.objects.filter(username="targetuser")
        if form.is_valid():  
            form.save()
            if notification:
                notification.send([user], "post_request", {"user": user})
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/create/')
    else:
        form = PostRequestForm()
    return render(request, 'createpostrequest.html', {
        'form': form,
})
```

but it throws an error "NoticeType matching query does not exist." If I replace "user" with specific usernames, I get global name not defined errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `from notification import models as notification` is very bad, you don't know for sure in code below what does `notification` mean. Then, what is `notification` in the view code?

Comment: the management.py code to which you refer is from the modules developer. I'm assuming there is a correct way to construct the view function as others have gotten the module to work, I'm just not sure how. I may be better off constructing my own notification scheme based on django's built in email handler. it just seems like a lot of work if modules already exist for this express purpose.

Comment: That seems to be just a signal, so clean up the code and understand how it's working, or write your own simple signal.